# Acumatica - Possible to create several numberingId with existing numberingId

Tags: acumatica

i have some problems with AutoNumberAttribute in Acumatica. In my Project Issue screen i can create new entity with existing numberingId (see screenshot below)
[Field selector with AutoNumberAttribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpFrK.png)

But other entities like POOrder, Case haven't this promlems. Code for this shown below:

```
 [Serializable]
[PXEMailSource]
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(ProjectIssueMaint))]
[PXCacheName(Messages.ProjectIssue.CacheName)]
public class ProjectIssue : BaseCache, IBqlTable, IAssign, IPXSelectable
{
    [PXDBIdentity]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible, DisplayName = Messages.ProjectIssue.NumberId)]
    public virtual int? ProjectIssueId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [PXDefault]
    [PXFieldDescription]
    [PXDBString(10, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.ProjectIssue.NumberId, Required = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<projectIssueCd>),
        typeof(projectIssueCd),
        typeof(projectId),
        typeof(projectTaskId),
        typeof(classId),
        typeof(summary),
        typeof(status),
        typeof(ownerID),
        Filterable = true)]
    [AutoNumber(typeof(ProjectManagementSetup.projectIssueNumberingId), typeof(createdDateTime))]
    public virtual string ProjectIssueCd
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public abstract class projectIssueCd : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public abstract class projectIssueId : IBqlField
    {
    }
}

 [Serializable]
[PXCacheName(Messages.ProjectManagementSetup.CacheName)]
public class ProjectManagementSetup : BaseCache, IBqlTable
{
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">aaaaaaaaaa")]
    [PXDefault(Constants.ProjectIssue.NumberingId)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Numbering.numberingID), DescriptionField = typeof(Numbering.descr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.ProjectManagementSetup.ProjectIssueNumberingSequence)]
    public virtual string ProjectIssueNumberingId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public abstract class projectIssueNumberingId : IBqlField
    {
    }
}

 public class ProjectIssueMaint : PXGraph<ProjectIssueMaint, ProjectIssue>
{
    [PXViewName(Messages.ProjectIssue.CacheName)]
    [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(ProjectIssue.status))]
    public PXSelect<ProjectIssue> ProjectIssue;

    [PXHidden]
    [PXCheckCurrent]
    public PXSetup<ProjectManagementSetup> ProjectManagementSetup;}

public class ProjectManagementSetupMaint : PXGraph<ProjectManagementSetupMaint>
{
    public PXSave<ProjectManagementSetup> Save;
    public PXCancel<ProjectManagementSetup> Cancel;

    public PXSelect<ProjectManagementSetup> ProjectManagementSetup;
}
```

I reproproduce this issue by change the last number field in the numbering sequence screen (see screenshot https://snag.gy/UpIe8a.jpg). 
So somebody know why this maybe happend? Any information will help me)

Comment: What is Base cache for ProjectIssue? Basically, what can cause such effect is existence of other cache keys in the ProjectIssue cache

Comment: Base Cache class has default fields in acumatica (Tstamp, CreatedById, CreatedByScreenId, CreatedDateTime, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedByScreenId, LastModifiedDateTime, NoteId)

Answer (score 1):

The AutoNumberAttribute completely relies on the configuration of the associated Numbering Sequence and does not have built-in validation to prevent insertion of the record with the duplicated number, which was generated by the AutoNumberAttribute. Since your table is built with [A Pair of Columns with Key Substitution in the UI](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5659adfe-3e4a-45a6-a94a-a33c2f955194), you must add a unique index consisting of the CompanyID and ProjectIssueCd columns to prevent the insertion of multiple ProjectIssue records with the same ProjectIssueCd on the database level.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ProjectIssue_ProjectIssueCd_Uindex] ON [dbo].[ProjectIssue]
(
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [ProjectIssueCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Comment: Yes, i fixed this issue in the same way, but I thought that the problem can be solved differently